# Why I can't call DbContext.ObjectContext directly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why I can't call `DbContext.ObjectContext` directly? I can do this `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext`

I think the inside mechanism is the implicitly implementation of interface like this

```
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        TestClass t = new TestClass(); 
        ((TestInterface)t).TestMethod(); 
        // I can't call t.TestMethod()
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    } 
} 

public interface TestInterface 
{ 
    void TestMethod(); 
} 

public class TestClass : TestInterface 
{ 
    void TestInterface.TestMethod() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("abcdefg"); 
    } 
}
```

I meet this problem before which is `IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable`, it has the generic version `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` and non-generic version `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()`, but you can only call the generic one rather than the non-generic one. Its because that the non-generic one is not type-safe and the author wants to hide it.

But what is the reason for the [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class?

Comment: If you want to convert IEnumerable to IEnumerable<T> you need to call OfType<T> or Cast<T>.

Answer (score 5):

Because ObjectContext is implemented explicitly in the DbContext class (as shown on the [MSDN - DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)) you have to explicitly cast your object to the Interface to call the Property.

" When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface. " - [MSDN - Explicit Interface Implementation Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect since `ObjectContext` has been deprecated in favor of `DbContext`. `DbContext` is a much more pleasant API than `ObjectContext`.

Comment: I would not say ObjectContex is deprecated but that it's preferable to use DbContext because it's so much easier to use. Since DbContext is built on top of ObjectContext and there are some things you cannot do with DbContext the interface allows getting ObjectContext instance to achieve these things

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code of DbContext class that is available on [Codeplex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c013cf02936a), the property ObjectContext is implemented explicitly. Here is the piece of code from the source (I have removed the comments):

```
ObjectContext IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext
        {
            get
            {
                InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes();
                return InternalContext.ObjectContext;
            }
        }
```

This is the reason why you won't be able to invoke the property ObjectContext using an object of DbContext without casting it to IObjectContextAdapter type.